# do actions on end of execution

Tags: signals, go, interrupt

I have an http server (launched using `http.Handle`) and I would like to do some operations.

How can I do that (on linux) ? Is it possible to do those operations in case of a ctrl-C ?

I'm not familiar with unix signals so the answer may be trivial.

Comment: The code would be good as a separate answer.  I understand it's fine to answer your own question (and even accept it!)  Attribution to kostix for sending you in the right direction is good too.

Comment: Ok, I'l make a separate answer (with clear attribution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe to the TERM and INT signals using the [signal](http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) package. But note that these signals are only sent when the process is killed explicitly; normal exit (initiated by the process itself) does not involve any sort of signals.  I think for normal exit just do something in the main routine (which supposedly should spawn worker goroutines and then wait on them).

Read `man 7 signal` for more general info on POSIX signals.

Answer (score 25):

Using kostix answer, I built this code (now adapted to Go1) to catch the interrupt signal and do some operations before exiting :

```
go func() {
    sigchan := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(sigchan, os.Interrupt)
    <-sigchan
    log.Println("Program killed !")
    
    // do last actions and wait for all write operations to end
    
    os.Exit(0)
}()

// start main program tasks
```

Comment: Why the size of `sigchan` is 10. I think `make(chan os.Signal, 1)` i.e with size `1` will work as well.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: @PrakashPandey The unbuffered `make(chan os.Signal)` would work well for this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose author is interested not only in <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and offer more broad solution for Linux (for Windows signals see [x/sys/windows](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows)):

```go
package main

import (
  "os"
  "os/signal"
  "syscall"
  "fmt"
)

func getFireSignalsChannel() chan os.Signal {

  c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
  signal.Notify(c,
    // https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html
    syscall.SIGTERM, // "the normal way to politely ask a program to terminate"
    syscall.SIGINT, // Ctrl+C
    syscall.SIGQUIT, // Ctrl-\
    syscall.SIGKILL, // "always fatal", "SIGKILL and SIGSTOP may not be caught by a program"
    syscall.SIGHUP, // "terminal is disconnected"
  )
  return c

}

func exit() {
  syscall.Kill(syscall.Getpid(), syscall.SIGTERM)
}

func main() {

  exitChan := getFireSignalsChannel()
  input, err := os.Open("input.txt")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer input.Close()
  <-exitChan
  fmt.Println("Exiting!")
  return
  // All main deferreds executed here even in case of panic.
  // Non-main deferreds are not executed here.

}
```

P.S. None of signals handles `os.Exit`.

With this configuration on <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or on receiving other signal program will push `os.Signal` into channel `exitChan` which will unblock `<-exitChan` operation and the `main` function will continue execution on the final lines, then return, then execute deferred functions.

#### Non-Main Deferreds

For non-main deferred you may:

1. Use https://github.com/tebeka/atexit
2. Move important resources into global array and release them in a main deferred. This solution is not perfect if you don't use transaction: 1) create resource, 2) add to array, -- which shouldn't be interrupted by exit. Also non-concurrent read-write access to a slice must be provided I guess.

Comment: Your code also works well in Windows. However, I find no way to listen to panics and Go crashes, other than directly `defer` in the main function. I tested here <https://github.com/patarapolw/atexit>