# Golang catch signals

Tags: go, signals, system-calls

I want to implement a "process wrapper" in Go. Basically what it will do, is launch a process (lets say a node server) and monitor it (catch signals like SIGKILL, SIGTERM ...)

I think the way to do is to launch the node server in a go routine using `syscall.Exec`:

```
func launchCmd(path string, args []string) {
  err := syscall.Exec(path, args, os.Environ())
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Then I'd like to catch every possible signals generated by the command executed by `syscall`. I'm pretty new to Go, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11268943/720999).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are three ways of executing a program in Go:

1. `syscall` package with [syscall.Exec](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Exec), [syscall.ForkExec](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#ForkExec), [syscall.StartProcess](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#StartProcess)
2. `os` package with [os.StartProcess](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#StartProcess)
3. `os/exec` package with [exec.Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)

[syscall.StartProcess](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#StartProcess) is low level. It returns a `uintptr` as a handle.

`os.StartProcess` gives you a nice `os.Process` struct that you can call [Signal](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Signal) on. `os/exec` gives you `io.ReaderWriter` to use on a pipe. Both use `syscall` internally.

Reading signals sent *from* a process other than your own seems a bit tricky. If it was possible, `syscall` would be able to do it. I don't see anything obvious in the higher level packages.

To receive a signal you can use [signal.Notify](http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#Notify) like this:

```
sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigc,
    syscall.SIGHUP,
    syscall.SIGINT,
    syscall.SIGTERM,
    syscall.SIGQUIT)
go func() {
    s := <-sigc
    // ... do something ...
}()
```

You just need to change the signals you're interested in listening to. If you don't specify a signal, it'll catch all the signals that can be captured.

You would use [syscall.Kill](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Kill) or [Process.Signal](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Signal) to map the signal. You can get the pid from `Process.Pid` or as a result from [syscall.StartProcess](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#StartProcess).

Comment: Thx I will try it. The idea is to have this wrapper monitored by upstart, it will just be used to keep track of what happened

Comment: Ok I can catch signals that are inputed to the program (if I do ^C for example) but can't get signals generated by my program executed by syscall. Any thought ?

Comment: @rmonjo You're trying to catch a signal sent *from* your program or *to*?

Comment: I want to catch signals sent from the program I execute in the `syscall`. I tried your solution, when I use `syscall.Exec` it seems that the program is forked and go just exits. Using `os/exec` however, I can catch signals such as child exit.

Comment: @rmonjo `signal.Notify` catches signals sent to your program. Catching from may be a bit tricky. Refined answer a bit.

Answer (score 40):

You can use [signal.Notify](http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#example_Notify) :

```
import (
"os"
"os/signal"
"syscall"
)

func main() {
    signalChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
    signal.Notify(signalChannel, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        sig := <-signalChannel
        switch sig {
        case os.Interrupt:
            //handle SIGINT
        case syscall.SIGTERM:
            //handle SIGTERM
        }
    }()
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Baba, Why make buffered channel of size 2?

Answer (score 2):

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGHUP, syscall.SIGQUIT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGSEGV)
    for {
        s := <-c
        switch s {
        case syscall.SIGQUIT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT:
            return
        case syscall.SIGHUP:
        case syscall.SIGSEGV:
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while this may answer the question, I think it would be much more useful with a little bit of explanation (also for future readers!). Why do you catch which signals? Why do you do what in which case?