# Capturing ctrl+c or any other process terminating signals in windows and linux with golang

Tags: linux, windows, go, signals

I am trying to build a chatroom application in go and I want to call logout function when client uses ctrl+c or presses close buttom of the terminal. 
I tried methods given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268943/golang-is-it-possible-to-capture-a-ctrlc-signal-and-run-a-cleanup-function-in) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106749/golang-catch-signals) but they were not capturing any signals(tried in Windows 10 and Fedora 23). Here is my code snippet,

```
sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigc,
    syscall.SIGHUP,
    syscall.SIGINT,
    syscall.SIGTERM,
    syscall.SIGQUIT)
go func() {
    _ = <-sigc
    fmt.Println("ctrl+c pressed")
    client.Logout()
}()
```

I have some other functions running concurrently using goroutine, is it the reason behind this function not capturing any signals?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That captures signals just fine on unix, so you need to show the accompanying code.  I'm not really familiar with windows, with IIRC you can't catch ctrl+c as a signal and it has to be handled by the terminal.

Comment: @JimB rest of the code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/GOOFS/go-goof-Talk/blob/master/client/client.go). But that does not have the code snippet I mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the docs on `os.Signal`, it should be possible to catch interrupts on Windows: https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#hdr-Windows. I haven't tested this personally, though.

I suspect your problem is that you should only use signals imported from `os`, such as `os.Interrupt`, instead of `syscall`.

From https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Signal:

> The only signal values guaranteed to be present on all systems are Interrupt (send the process an interrupt) and Kill (force the process to exit).

And from https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#pkg-overview:

> The primary use of syscall is inside other packages that provide a more portable interface to the system, such as "os", "time" and "net". Use those packages rather than this one if you can.

So, change your `signal.Notify` call to catch only the `os.Interrupt` signal.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and documentation quotes. I also found that one more go routine was clashing with it and changing the order of function call also helped me to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer. Couldn't figure out why my code was not catching `SIGINT` - putting the goroutine that catches as the very first code in `main` did the trick