# Is there something like finally() in Go just opposite to what init()?

Tags: go, shutdown-hook, application-shutdown

Is there something in Go which do just opposite to what `init()` do inside a package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was discussed before by the Go team, and the conclusion was not to add support for it. [Quoting minux](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/qBQ0bK2zvQA):

> Personally, I prefer the style where program exit is handled exactly same as program crash.
>   I believe no matter how hard you try, your program can still crash under some unforeseen
>   situations; for example, memory shortage can bring any well-behave Go program to a crash,
>   and there is nothing you can do about it; so it's better to design for them.
>   If you follow this, you won't feel the need for atexit to clean up (because when your program
>   crash, atexit won't work, so you simply can't depend on it).

But you still have some options:

#### Handling <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>

If you want to do something when your program is terminated by <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> ([SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT)), you can do so, see:

[Golang: Is it possible to capture a Ctrl+C signal and run a cleanup function, in a "defer" fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268943/golang-is-it-possible-to-capture-a-ctrlc-signal-and-run-a-cleanup-function-in)

#### Object Finalizer

Also note that you can register a finalizer function for a pointer value. When the garbage collector finds an unreachable block with an associated finalizer, it clears the association and runs `f(x)` in a separate goroutine.

You can register such finalizer with [`runtime.SetFinalizer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) which might be enough for you, but note:

> There is no guarantee that finalizers will run before a program exits, so typically they are useful only for releasing non-memory resources associated with an object during a long-running program.

See this example:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    go func() {
        p := &Person{"Bob", 20}
        runtime.SetFinalizer(p, func(p2 *Person) {
            log.Println("Finalizing", p2)
        })
        runtime.GC()
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    log.Println("Done")
}
```

Output ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_Z1Tz5acUl)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Finalizing &{Bob 20}
2009/11/10 23:00:01 Done
```

Comment: I'd argue that (ab)using finalizers to do "user-space" cleanups is a clear code smell.  Instead, one should supposedly design the whole application around the idea of controlled shutdown, and then perform that controlled shutdown when certain conditions are met (like receiving `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`). [This](http://blog.labix.org/2011/10/09/death-of-goroutines-under-control) is a good starting point.

Comment: [See also](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/1y5fg1/critique_graceful_http_shutdown/).

Comment: I'd also add that creating a package that needs an "atexit" hook is a bad design whatsoever.  The package should just export "something" which the user has to initialize explicitly and deinitialize explicitly, and then just let the user to that -- when it's really needed.

Comment: @kostix I agree, it's bad design to rely on such functions, that's why there is no first-class support for it. Just showing the  available options.