# In go, is there a way to execute code on termination of the program?

Tags: go, deferred-execution

I know you can define functions called `init` in any package, and these function will be executed before `main`. I use this to open my log file and my DB connection.

Is there a way to define code that will be executed when the program ends, either because it reaches the end of the `main` function or because it was interrupted ? The only way I can think of is by manually calling a deffered `terminate` function on each package used by main, but that's quite verbose and error prone.

Comment: If after reading all of this (and maybe watched [this](http://pyvideo.org/video/647/make-sure-your-programs-crash)), you still want atexit - have a look at https://github.com/tebeka/atexit :)

Comment: Is [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403862/do-actions-on-end-of-execution) useful ? That's how I execute actions on end of execution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The C `atexit` functionality was considered by the Go developers and the idea of adopting it was rejected.

From one of the related [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/qBQ0bK2zvQA/discussion) at golang-nuts:

[Russ Cox](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/qBQ0bK2zvQA/vmOu9uhkYH0J):

> Atexit may make sense in single-threaded, short-lived
>   programs, but I am skeptical that it has a place in a
>   long-running multi-threaded server.
>   I've seen many C++ programs that hang on exit because
>   they're running global destructors that don't really need to
>   run, and those destructors are cleaning up and freeing
>   memory that would be reclaimed by the operating system
>   anyway, if only the program could get to the exit system call.
>   Compared to all that pain, needing to call Flush when you're
>   one with a buffer seems entirely reasonable and is
>   necessary anyway for correct execution of long-running
>   programs.
>
> Even ignoring that problem, atexit introduces even more
>   threads of control, and you have to answer questions like
>   do all the other goroutines stop before the atexit handlers
>   run?  If not, how do they avoid interfering?  If so, what if
>   one holds a lock that the handler needs?  And on and on.
>
> I'm not at all inclined to add Atexit.

[Ian Lance Taylor](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/qBQ0bK2zvQA/W-GQviEvVSUJ):

> The only fully reliable mechanism is a wrapper program that invokes the 
>   real program and does the cleanup when the real program completes.  That 
>   is true in any language, not just Go.
>
> In my somewhat unformed opinion, os.AtExit is not a great idea.  It is 
>   an unstructured facility that causes stuff to happen at program exit 
>   time in an unpredictable order.  It leads to weird scenarios like 
>   programs that take a long time just to exit, an operation that should be 
>   very fast.  It also leads to weird functions like the C function _exit, 
>   which more or less means exit-but-don't-run-atexit-functions.
>
> That said, I think a special exit function corresponding to the init 
>   function is an interesting idea.  It would have the structure that 
>   os.AtExit lacks (namely, exit functions are run in reverse order of when 
>   init functions are run).
>
> But exit functions won't help you if your program gets killed by the 
>   kernel, or crashes because you call some C code that gets a segmentation 
>   violation.

Answer (score -1):

In general, I agree with jnml's answer. Should you however still want to do it, you could use [defer](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) in the `main()` function, like this: http://play.golang.org/p/aUdFXHtFOM.

Comment: Deferring functions from `main` only works when the program terminates by finishing `main`, not if it exits via `os.Exit`, in contrast to the original `atexit` which also works when calling `exit`.

Comment: Nor does it work when the program terminates with an unrecovered `panic`.

Comment: @peterSO You could, however, recover in the deferred function, so that's no real argument against `defer` in `main`.

Comment: @nemo: Translating my comment to pseudo-code: `if panic and not recover then not defer;`.

Comment: It still won't get called if os.Exit is used.

Comment: @peterSO it does call defer on panic https://play.golang.org/p/bxfsjsekTal