# Writing to a mmap-allocated slice panics

Tags: go, mmap

Scenario is to cache realtime streaming data into memory-mapped regions backed by files. The goal is to make the state fault tolerant using `mmap`.

Using `mmap` within application would avoid  relying on Redis key-value store.

Below is the program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/edsrzf/mmap-go"
)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.OpenFile("./file", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    defer f.Close()

    mmap, _ := mmap.Map(f, mmap.RDWR, 0)
    defer mmap.Unmap()
    fmt.Println(string(mmap))

    mmap[0] = 'X'
    mmap.Flush()
}
```

---

```
$ go build -gcflags -m=2 -o main cmd/layer/main.go
$ ./main

panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /..//cmd/layer/main.go:21 +0x1d7
```

---

Why `mmap[0] = 'X'` could not write data to file?

Comment: `mmap` is an empty slice, use `mmap = append(mmap, 'X')` instead of set by index.

Comment: @Trock: But then your new slice isn't going to be backed by the file.

Comment: Please note that your approach does not make your state fault-tolerant unless you take extra measures such as using [`msync(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/msync) (that's what `Flush` is supposed to do in a data type provided by your package of choice). Even then, w/o checksumming the result as well, this is not fault-tolerance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is empty, so your slice is empty too. You have to allocate some bytes for the file first, then try to change the slice you got from the `mmap.Map()` or `mmap.MapRegion()`:

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/edsrzf/mmap-go"
)

var testPath = "./file"

func initFile() {
    size := int64(10 * 1024 * 1024)
    fd, err := os.Create(testPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create output")
    }
    _, err = fd.Seek(size-1, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to seek")
    }
    _, err = fd.Write([]byte{0})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Write failed")
    }
    err = fd.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to close file")
    }
}

func main() {
    f, _ := os.OpenFile("./file", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    defer f.Close()

    mem, _ := mmap.Map(f, mmap.RDWR, 0)
    defer mem.Unmap()

    mem[0] = 'X'
    mem.Flush()
}
```

Note that creating the file in `initFile()` is not human readable, you can make a string of fixed size and then write it to the file, so the content of your `mem` becomes human readable

Comment: This code gives error: `CreateFileMapping: The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid`

Comment: @overexchange I guess you are running it on windows and maybe a process is also accessing this file. Does restarting the system fixes it? :D

Comment: Yes running on windows

Comment: Another relevant question from your code, How to close file? If the Pod is crashed.. because this code runs on kubernetes Pod

Comment: @overexchange in this code everything is fine because we are running it 1 time and we added `defer f.Close()` so there is no problem. But on a process that is up for more time, you should have a handling mechanism to gracefully shut down your process ( like catching the `syscall.SIGTERM` and then close the file and other things you have on your code, like db connection etc. ) check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403862/do-actions-on-end-of-execution

Comment: Graceful shutdown is different from panic, where GoLang binary can crash